# Python __format__ never called

Tags: python, f-string

Newbie in python and I do not understand why **format**  is never called!
I do not want to overide the STR and read quite a few documentaions.
I am sure missed simple thing!

```
import locale
import datetime

LOCALE = "fr_CA.utf-8"


class Data:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, LOCALE)

    def __init__(self):
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, LOCALE)

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        print("---> " + format_spec)
        if not format_spec:
            return "A formatted Foo"
        return f"A formatted Foo, but also {format_spec}!"

    def run(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(f'1---> {now}')
        print(f'2---> {now.strftime("%c")}.')
        print(f"3---> {now.strftime('%x %X')}.")
        print("4---> {}.".format(now, 'dt_fmt'))
        print('5---> {now}'.format("Bar", now=now))
        print(f'6---> {now:Bart}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = Data()
    data.run()
```

And the result I have is:

```
1---> 2023-09-20 09:13:36.691234
2---> 2023-09-20 09:13:36.
3---> 2023-09-20 09:13:36.
4---> 2023-09-20 09:13:36.691234.
5---> 2023-09-20 09:13:36.691234
6---> Bart
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're just calling the `__format__` method of a `datetime.datetime` instance, and the `Data.__format__` method you've written has nothing to do with that!

The way it works is that when your code says `"{:<fmt>}".format(foo)"`, Python will call `foo.__format__("<fmt>")`. So if you want to change what happens when you write `"{:<fmt>}".format(now)"`, you should subclass `datetime.datetime` and override the `__format__` method of that class.

For example, if you add `print("{:xyz}".format(self))` to your `run()` method, or `print("{:abc}".format(data))` to the main part of your code, then you'll see that your `__format__` method is called:

```
class Data:
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        print("---> " + format_spec)
        if not format_spec:
            return "A formatted Foo"
        return f"A formatted Foo, but also {format_spec}!"

    def run(self):
        print("{:xyz}".format(self))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = Data()
    data.run()
    print("{:abc}".format(data))
```

Output:

```
---> xyz
A formatted Foo, but also xyz!
---> abc
A formatted Foo, but also abc!
```

Answer (score 0):

The _ *format* _ method in your Data class is not being called because you are not using the format function or f-strings to format instances of your class. Maybe try it like this:

```
def run(self):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f'1---> {now}')
    print(f'2---> {now.strftime("%c")}.')
    print(f"3---> {now.strftime('%x %X')}.")
    print("4---> {}.".format(now))
    print('5---> {now}'.format(now=now))
    print(f'6---> {now:Bart}')  # This will call __format__
```

Comment: Can you explain why `print(f'6---> {now:Bart}')` would result in the `__format__` method of OP's class being called?

Comment: you are right. This cannot work. use the other answer as this looks way better